# Cannot install Hmisc package in R Connect 3.6?

Tags: r

I've been trying to create a geographic dashboard using the shiny package in R connect.

To do so, I need the Hmisc package, but whenever I try to install it, I get the error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘interp’ is not available for package ‘latticeExtra’
* removing ‘/home/eryk.wisniewski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/latticeExtra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘latticeExtra’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘latticeExtra’ is not available for package ‘Hmisc’
* removing ‘/home/eryk.wisniewski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Hmisc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Hmisc’ is not available for package ‘rms’
* removing ‘/home/eryk.wisniewski/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rms’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried switching R versions, but no avail, I tried installing individual packages but I get similar errors, since these packages seem to depend on each other?

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it, I'm just a newbie starting out and this issue has been plaguing me all weekend.

Comment: You said you tried switching R versions, what is the most-recent version of R that you tried (and failed)? What is `options("repos")`? It seems odd that `interp` (the first error) is unavailable, as it only requires [`R (≥ 3.5.0)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interp/index.html).

Comment: Originally I was on 3.5.2 and didn't work... i was told by a co-worker that we use 3.6 generally in work for the server...

Comment: CRAN                                              
"https://rstudio-pm-prod.zurich.com/test-cran/latest" Internal  "https://rstudio-pm-prod.zurich.com/aux-cran/latest" 
                                       SecureInternal 
"https://rstudio-pm-prod.zurich.com/test-cran/latest"

Comment: Did you say no to "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)"?

Comment: Your `repos` appear to be internal-only. I suggest you reach out to your company's IT (or whomever) to help inform why `interp` is not being found. It's feasible that they are mirroring common packages and may just need to add that (and perhaps a few more from this list) to their packages-to-mirror list.